# i have a object array how to remove the duplicate values and count them

Tags: php, arrays

```
array(3) { 
   [0]=> object(stdClass)#43 (5) { 
      ["id"]=> string(3) "148" 
      ["questionResId"]=> string(2) "76" 
      ["optionText"]=> string(17) "some Cute Moment." 
      ["optionId"]=> string(2) "30" 
      ["optionAnswer"]=> string(4) "test" } 
   [1]=> object(stdClass)#38 (5) { 
      ["id"]=> string(3) "142" 
      ["questionResId"]=> string(2) "72" 
      ["optionText"]=> string(17) "some Cute Moment." 
      ["optionId"]=> string(2) "30" 
      ["optionAnswer"]=> string(4) "test" } 
   [2]=> object(stdClass)#41 (5) { 
      ["id"]=> string(3) "221" 
      ["questionResId"]=> string(3) "136" 
      ["optionText"]=> string(17) "some Cute Moment." 
      ["optionId"]=> string(2) "30" 
      ["optionAnswer"]=> string(4) "Good" } 
}
```

i have the object of array like above how to remove the duplicate values from an array in PHP and count the occurrence of every element

out put like

```
test 2 
good 1
```

Comment: At [so] you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/)**.

Comment: Use array_unique function for remove duplicates. http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**array_count_values**](http://php.net/manual/sr/function.array-count-values.php) gets result you want

```
array_count_values(array_map(function($x) { return $x->optionAnswer;}, $arr));
```

result

```
Array( [test] => 2, [Good] => 1 )
```

Comment: you are welcome